# Jquery Ajax Autcomplete only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a category list and I want to send the id as parameter to get subcategories.

But I want to save the response into an array, I don't want to make the ajax call for evevry autcomplete..just when I'm changeing the item from list. I want to save as an array because if I'm doing the request everytime I can't show for example only one item, i'm appending all the subcategories.

Here is my actual code

```
   $('#category').change(function(){ 
        var category_id = $(this).val();
        console.log(category_id);
    $("#type").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/get-sub-by-cat",
                type: "POST",
               data: { 
                  'category_id': category_id
                 },
                success: function (data) {
                   // console.log(data);
                    response($.map(data.data.subcategories, function (item) {
                       console.log(item.name);
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.name,
                            id: item.id
                        };



                    }));
                }
            });
        },

        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#type').val(ui.item.value);
            var id_subcategory= ui.item.id;
            $("#subcat").val(id_subcategory);
         },
         change: function (event, ui) {
             if (!ui.item) {
                 this.value = '';
                 $("#err-message").remove();
                 $(".type-label").before("<p id='err-message' class='col-xs-12 no-padding' style='color:red;margin-bottom:0;'>Please select only from suggested options</p>");
                 }
              else{
                 $("#err-message").hide();
             }
        },
        autoFocus: true

    });

 });
```

Comment: I don't think you need to save the response yourself as the browser should be caching the response anyway.

Comment: @George how can I do that? in the best way?